# Grails , domain properties .. How can i get at the value?

Tags: grails, properties

In a domain class I have a property

```
class Domain {
   String someValue
}
```

I can get at that directly via the property value - domainInstance.someValue

I now have a requirement to create a hierarchy such that if someValue isn't set I get it from some other property of the domain  ..

So I implemented my own version of getSomeValue

...

```
getSomeValue(){
  someValue ?: someOtherValue 
}
```

But this just invokes itself .. Can I get at the value 'someValue' directly or will it always invoke the getSomeValue method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy automatically generates gets and sets:

```
class Domain {
 String someValue  
}
Domain domain = new Domain(somevalue:"somevalue")
//or domain.setSomeValue("someValue)
println domain.getSomeValue
```

if you want to access directly just do:

```
domain.@someValue
```